# What is the correct term for this method of cooking?

Tags: language

I'm a reluctant cook at the best of times but I'm interested to know what I just did.

I got a *massive* bone for the dog from the butcher. There was quite a lot of meat on it so I thought the dog and I should both have some benefit.

I placed the entire bone (I can't identify what it was anatomically maybe backbone) in my non-stick frying pan with a tiny bit of olive oil. I heated it up to max to brown it and then turned it down to the lowest setting and left it for the whole evening with a Pyrex lid on.

It was thoroughly cooked through and tasted good.

So what did I do? Did I fry it? Roast it? What would you call this?

---

NOTE: I didn't add anything at all, not even salt or spices. There was a teaspoon of olive oil to lubricate the pan and then I stuck the lid on and left it.

Comment: I'd say "slow pan roasted stove top" ? :-)

Comment: @Max - Sounds good to me!

Comment: @Max Please! Make an answer! This question (+1) deserves that.

Comment: Was it all on the stove top? If so I would remove the "pan roasted" bit - this implies the bone was started on the stove top and then moved into the oven to complete.

Comment: I hope you had a mess of beans to fry up in that greasy pan when you were done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say "slow pan roasted stove top".

It's not stewed, it's not braised, it's not pan fried, it's not oven roasted.

Answer (score 0):

This would fit with the dictionary definition of slow-cooked.

https://www.lexico.com/definition/slow-cook